# v4l2loopback-ctl set-fps or set-caps results in errors like can't parse or /sys/devices/virtual/video4linux no such file or directory?

Tags: ubuntu, v4l2loopback

Possibly pertinent information: Ubuntu 20.04, Logitech 1080p USB Webcam, NVidia GTX 1080

I installed v4l2loopback and I got it working using [one solution](https://github.com/fangfufu/Linux-Fake-Background-Webcam) out there but it required that I specify /dev/video5 in the argument as the device. I tried using v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video5 and it seemed to take but when I tried using the command to force fps or set-caps I got strange errors like:

```
v4l2loopback-ctl set-fps /dev/video5 24
can't parse device
```

or

```
v4l2loopback-ctl set-caps "image/jpeg, width=1280, height=720, fps=30/1" /dev/video5
cat: /sys/devices/virtual/video4linux/video5/format: No such file or directory
unknown control 'keep_format'
```

There is no video4linux dir, not sure why it needs that to be there.

Other info:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
v4l2loopback (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
    /dev/video9

Rift Sensor: CV1 External Camer (usb-0000:00:14.0-10):
    /dev/video3
    /dev/video4

Rift Sensor: CV1 External Camer (usb-0000:00:14.0-6.3):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1

UVC Camera (046d:0821) (usb-0000:00:14.0-9.1):
    /dev/video5
    /dev/video6

Rift Sensor: CV1 External Camer (usb-0000:00:14.0-9.4.2):
    /dev/video7
    /dev/video8
```

and

```
dmesg | grep -i "Camera"
[4.637790] input: UVC Camera (046d:0821) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9.1/1-9.1:1.2/input/input21
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `set-fps`

your syntax is wrong (with all *released* versions of `v4l2loopback-ctl`, as of 2020-12-18):

```bsh
$ v4l2loopback-ctl -h | grep set-fps
     set-fps <FPS> /dev/videoX  Set device fps (if format is already
```

so it should be: `v4l2loopback-ctl set-fps 24 /dev/video5`

the [upstream README](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/#forcing-fps) has fps and device swapped - but this is because the next (as of now unreleased) version of `v4l2loopback` will have the parameters swapped; and the upstream repository already contains these changes and has updated its documentation accordingly.

#### `set-caps`

if you don't have a `/sys/devices/virtual/video4linux/video5/` directory, then you have no loopback-device named `/dev/video5`.

the `v4l2loopback-ctl` utility is **only** usable with loopback devices. it is not a general tool to set framerates and formats on arbitrary video devices. so:

- make sure that the driver is loaded
- make sure to load the driver in such a way that it creates the `dev/video5` device.

something like this should do the trick (you mugt unload the driver, before you load it with a new parameter set):

```bsh
$ sudo rmmod v4l2loopback
$ sudo modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=5
```

apart from that: the `v4l2loopback-ctl` script uses a simple gstreamer pipeline to force the format onto the device. unfortunately this pipeline won't be able to produce a valid `image/jpeg` stream, so right now you you are on your own if you want to force the format to JPEG...

Comment: When using your first set-fps suggestion the error changed: tee: /sys/devices/virtual/video4linux/video5/format: No such file or directory
Set fps failed. Which brings us to the second suggestion, /dev/video5 exists, I looked and it even works in zoom with that Linux Fake background solution I linked.

Comment: I think I read your answer wrong. /dev/video5 literally is the Logitech webcam I have, not the loopback. I have to point v4l2loopback to that in order for it to know which device is the actual webcam because I see several video# files in my dev dir for whatever reason. What driver are you referring to?

Comment: Oh the extra devices are from the Rift sensors.

Comment: i've updated the answer to explain that `v4l2loopback-ctl` can only be used for *loopback devices* and not  for firing snowballs.